LiDAR system for detecting animals
I hope this is the correct SE for my question. This page says that I can ask about suitable sensors. If I am in the wrong place, moderator please notify me so that I can delete it.
Question:
Has there been any success in finding animals of the size of a Red European Deer and a Human through forest canopy using a Lidar?
I have been researching the feasibility of using LiDAR to find deers and possible poachers through canopy using Lidar. UAV Lidars can pick up features even as small as 5 cm.
So, at least, I expect, an UAV Lidar should be able to do this. Even if it does not construct a complete point cloud, showing the entire contour of a deer, it should have sufficient points to roughly guess that it is a Deer.
Looking for possibilities, I find Billy the Elephant (picture below) but he was imaged by a terrestrial lidar.

I also found this paper, which finds cows. The point density is low, but you can still see it and recognize this as a cow.

My question is, can it be done using canopy penetrating radar? Even if I see a deer with similar point density, I am happy.
Please point me to some published (peer reviewed or other) results.
Edit #1:
We are all familiar with this cat in panorama mode:  from reddit
But, if our LiDAR was to detect a moving deer with such distortions, I would not mind either. I assume some deers run very fast and will be very distorted, and others will eat grass in a stationary position, and will not be that distorted. Then I could run a Machine Vision to extract the better results.
Thank you.

with lidar, the chance of detection is low if the animal moves before enough data points are gathered ... not sure about radar, wouldn't it detect trees?

Good point. I edited the question

To detect animals and poachers, I would rather think that other sensors are more appropriate, e.g. thermal infrared. Or maybe regular or IR cameras (for night sight) and some AI model trained on 'animal behind canopy' images.

@JRTG of course.
But can you use a LIDAR in this case?
